# Composition of asymptotic equal function

Tags: real-analysis

Could you advise me how to proof below property of asymptotic equal functions?

If $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f_{1}(x)}{f_{2}(x)}=1$ and $\lim_{x \to a}  \frac{g_{1}(x)}{g_{2}(x)}=1$, how to prof that $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{(g_{1}\circ f_{1})(x)}{(g_{2}\circ f_{2})(x)}=1$?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the Math.SE. I may be wrong but it seems to me that your condition can only hold iff $\lim_{x\to a}f_1=\lim_{x\to a}f_2=a$: the limit condition on implies their asymptotic equivalence only if their argument $x$ tends to $a$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. There is no assumptions about $f_{1},f_{2},g_{1},g_{2}$ limits, but probably they schould be $a$. Any ideas about composition limit?

Comment: why do you even think $g_1\circ f_1$ makes any sense? You need more precise hypotheses.

Comment: I think about $f_{1}, f_{2}$ as a cumulative functions, and $g_{1}, g_{2}$ as 
as the inverse of cumulative functions of chi squared distribution. But i leave them as general functions

Comment: But i leave them as general functions to simplify my question